# Java & Guice - How to deal with inheritance and abstraction?

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, guice

In the following code is it required to annotate the constructor of my base class with "Inject"? what if the base class is an abstract class?

Is it required to call super in my constructor when using DI?

```
public class Base {

   @Inject
   public Base(IConfig config) {
      // Do stuff
   }
}

public class A extends Base {

   @Inject
   public A(IConfig config) {
      super(config);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly would you want to extend a concrete injectable class? Most of the cases I've personally seen where people try to do this can be better addressed through other means. For example, if it's to change how constructor params are provided, then something like `@Provides` methods tend to work much better. If it's to override concrete methods, that's a sign that the base class doesn't address realistic use cases and needs redesign anyway. And the Guice best practices wiki warns against `@Inject public` constructors (see http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you want to bind. If you bind `Base` to `A` (`bind(Base.class).to(A.class)`), then yes, the second constructor and @Inject is needed, but the one on Base is not. If you plan to construct also `Base`, you need the `@Inject`.

Concerning the call to `super()`, Java needs it (this has nothing to do with Guice) if you have only a single constructor with IConfig. But nothing prevent you to remove it if you don't need to inject `IConfig` in `Base`.